# python pandas match values between two columns when one column is not null

Tags: python, pandas, null, match, string-matching

Didn't find the similar question here.

Below please find the table:

```
         A       B       C      D
  0     pen     nan     dfds    1238
  1     Apple   pen     fsd      324
  2     Peach   nan     kd       878
  3     grape   peach   jil      9kj
  4     laptop  nan     lks      873p
  5     light   grape   kje      7623d
  6     nan     grape   3r43     kj23
  7     nan     grape   3fdf     8734d
```

1. if column B is not null, then compare the values in B with the values in A and try to find the matched value. e.g. "pen" in 1st row in column A = "pen" in 2nd row in column B.
2. if identified the matched values, need to find the index in column A. e.g. "pen" is a matched value, the index for "pen" in column A is 0.

my expected output is:

```
         A       B        C      D 
  0     pen     nan     dfds    1238
  2     Peach   nan     kd       878
  3     grape   peach   jil      9kj
```

And keep original index number as in the output example

I know how to do the matching job between A and B. My code is

```
df2=df[df[['A','B']].nunique(axis=1)==1]
```

But i don't know how to add the condition when column B is not null. And i don't want to do loop iterations since the dataset is super large.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think, in point 1 of your question, do you mean column "**C**" is not null?? But whatever, I'll demonstrate it by taking column "**B**".

For this, you have to create a new dataframe containing not null values only.

```
df_not_null = df.dropna(subset=['B'])
```

Then you can compare whatever you want to compare.

```
df2 = df_not_null[df_not_null[['A','B']].nunique(axis=1)==1]
```

Comment: sorry for my typo. yes, when column B is not null. The problem is if remove all rows when B is nan, the first row will be removed, too. But actually it has a matched value "pen".

Comment: Can you please explain point 1 again? Do you want to check, if B is not null, then only your compare function works? or you just want to compare ignoring the fact that B is null or not?

Comment: Yes, first B is not null, second, compare A and B. the prerequisite is B is not null.